# How would I make my bot react with random emoji?

Tags: bots, discord.js

**I use Discord.js, here's** my code so far;

```
    if (message.content === '..react') {
        message.react('')
        message.react('')
        message.react('')
        message.react('')
        message.react('')
        message.react('')
        message.react('')
        message.react('')
        message.react('')
        message.react('')
        message.react('')
        const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setDescription('I just reacted with diffrent emojies! React to your favorite!')
        .setColor(0x1ED5E7)
      message.channel.send(embed);
    }
  });
```

I want it to react with any emojis that's available, without going over 11 reactions. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Js means "JavaScript", not "java". Please tag your question correctly, the two languages are unrelated

Comment: My bad @ErwinBolwidt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to react random emojies you can get all client emoji.id , shuffle it, then slice and react in array map. I do not know methods to get standard unicode emoji lists in Discord, so maybe you need to great all unnciode emoji array and then concat its with emojilist array.

React with 11 random available client emoji you can somethink like this

```
  if (message.content === '..react') {
    let emojiList = bot.emojis.map(emoji => emoji.id)
    let randTenEmojies = shuffle(emojiList).splice(0,11)
    randTenEmojies.map(emoji => message.react(emoji))
    const embed = new RichEmbed()
    .setDescription('I just reacted with diffrent emojies! React to your favorite!')
    .setColor(0x1ED5E7)
  message.channel.send(embed);
}
});

const shuffle = (arr) => {
    var j, temp;
    for(var i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i + 1));
        temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```